# If $f(x):=\mu(\overline{B}(x,r))$ show that $f$ is upper semicontinuous

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

> Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure in $\mathbb R^n$, for fixed $r>0$ define $f(x):=\mu(\overline{B}(x,r))$ show that $f$ is upper semicontinuous.

Like $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is a closed set then $1_{\overline{B}(x,r)}$ is upper semicontinuous and hence given $x_n \to x$ we know that
$$\limsup 1_{\overline{B}(x_n,r)} \leq 1_{\overline{B}(x,r)}$$
by the reverse Fatou´s lemma
$$\limsup f(x_n)=\limsup \int1_{\overline{B}(x_n,r)}  \leq\int \limsup 1_{\overline{B}(x_n,r)} \leq \int 1_{\overline{B}(x,r)}=f(x)$$
But I can't be sure if these are correct, because I can´t find a function $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^n ;\mu)$ such that $1_{\overline{B}(x_n,r)} \leq g$ , $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ and these is a fundamental hyp. for the reverse Fatou´s lemma.
Any hint or help? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Since $x_n\to x,$ $\bar B(x_n,r)\subset\bar B(x,2r)$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_n \to x$, $x_n \in B_r(x)$ if $n > N$ for some $N$. So without loss of generality, we can assume that $x_n \in B_r(x)$ $\forall n$. Therefore, we can pick $g := \mu(B_{2r}(x))$. Since $\mu$ is a Radon measure, g should be finite.The remaining proof follows your original arguments.